# How to install Cudatoolkit on AWS EMR to enable distributed training in Tensorflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run some tensorflow-recommenders code on an AWS EMR cluster.

My testing Spark cluster has a g3.4xlarge master node and a few g3.4xlarge core nodes.

I have a bootstrap action which does the following:

```
sudo yum -y install cudatoolkit
sudo yum -y install nvidia
```

At runtime however it appears that some of the cudatoolkit libs aren't found:

```
Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0 name: Tesla M60 computeCapability: 5.2
coreClock: 1.1775GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 7.44GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 149.31GiB/s
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
```

Would I need to augment the LD_LIBRARY_PATH within my bootstrap action? I'd worry about it taking effect without a reboot and I'd worry about trying to reboot from within a bootstrap action.

Has anyone else come across this type of problem? Any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: That tensorflow build plainly needs CUDA 11.0

Comment: Thought so too, @talonmies.  I have tried `sudo yum install cuda` but to no avail; still got the error.

Also tried applying a readymade Amazon DLAMI with TF 2.4.1 and cuda (doesn't state what version) but that yielded the below error.  Which poses the question of how to cleanly shut down/remove Nvidia before DLAMI can do its tasks...

> ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.